# Express.js Route Returns Null Value for Database Query Using _id Field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I have the following Express.js route

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
       try {
        console.log(`Request Body :\n${req.body}`);
        const {orderIDs} = req.body;
        console.log(`Order IDs : \n${orderIDs}`);

        for (const orderID of orderIDs) {
            const order = await Purchases.findById(orderID);
            console.log(order)
            const orderData = order.orderData;

            // Update stock Levels
            for (const item of orderData) {
                const product = await Products.findOne({productCode: item.productCode});
                await increaseQuantity(product.quantity, item.quantity, item.productCode);
            }
            // Update Purchases Table
            await updateOrderStatusPurchases(orderID);
            // Update TxnAudit Table
            await updateStatusTXN_AUDIT(orderID);
        }

        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Pending orders received'});
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while canceling orders' });
    }
  });
```

For some reason, whenever I try to retrieve a particular order from the database using the _id field results in a null value even though the document does exist in the database.

I have tried replacing `await Purchases.findById(orderID)` with `await Purchases.findOne({"_id": orderID)` with no luck.

I have also made sure that the Atlas User has the right permissions and that I am connecting to the correct mongodb instance.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

**Update**

The request is coming from a database trigger from the atlas console, as shown in the code below

```
import axios from 'axios'

exports = async function updatePurchases() {
    const purchasesCollection = context.services.get("LegendaryShields").db("test").collection("purchases");

    const twoDaysAgo = new Date();
    twoDaysAgo.setDate(twoDaysAgo.getDate() - 2);

    const query = {
        status: { $in: ["Awaiting payment", "TXN_AUTH_UNSUCCESSFUL", "TXN_FAILED"] },
        purchasedAt: { $lte: twoDaysAgo }
    };

    const projection = { _id: 1 };

    try {
        const purchases = await purchasesCollection.find(query, projection).toArray();
        const orderIDs = purchases.map((purchase) => purchase._id);

        const url = "http://ec2-13-246-182-9.af-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5300/cancel_order";

        const response = await axios.post(url, { orderIDs }, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });

        if (response.status === 200) {
            console.log(`API response: ${JSON.stringify(response.data)}`);
        } else {
            console.error(`API request failed with status: ${response.status}`);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
};
```

As for the request body, this is shown below:

> Request Body :
> [object Object]
> Order IDs :
> 651a92d88799f214af2e8a5d,651c5aab28a1a56b70f8f4c8,652803ff12b17ae3aef24e15,6528e7eb427803d97a70abcf,6528ea3d427803d97a70abdf

Comment: show us request body from both client and server.

Comment: Hello @bogdanoff I have added the information that you requested, as you can see, the orderIDs are been succesfully received from the request body

Comment: try logging result of `Purchases.find({}, { _id: 1 })`

Comment: This gives the result ` [ { _id: new ObjectId("651c5aab28a1a56b70f8f4c8") }, { _id: new ObjectId("651f13534e4479e1bc18096e") }, ......]`. Which is all the ids in the database. Note that I have ommited some of the output as it may not all fit here.

Comment: After you do `const {orderIDs} = req.body;` can you do `console.log('type=', typeof orderIDs);`

Comment: And can you do `console.log('is an array=', Array.isArray(orderIDs));`

Comment: Hello @jQueeny the output of `console.log('type=', typeof orderIDs);` is `type= object` and the output of `console.log('is an array=', Array.isArray(orderIDs));` is `is an array= true`. My thoughts are that the problem doesn't lie with data type of the orderIDs variable but maybe with the query?

Comment: That's good, so that means you *do* have an array of ids and that your `for(of)` loop should work perfectly fine because `orderIDs` is iterable. Parking the design issues in your code (making numerous db calls inside a loop is classic code smell) you need to establish if you make at least one hit on an `orderID`. Mongoose `findById()` will cast a string id to an ObjectId for you so somewhere in your code use the first id in that `orderIDs` do a `const order = await Purchases.findById(orderIDs[0]);`. Do it in a `try/catch` block to see if it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
       try {
        console.log(`Request Body :\n${req.body}`);
        const {orderIDs} = req.body;
        console.log(`Order IDs : \n${orderIDs}`);

        for (const orderID of orderIDs) {
          // =====> console.log(orderID) can you log the order ID 
          // ====> you might loop  orderIDS.split(',')
            const order = await Purchases.findById(orderID);
            console.log(order)
            const orderData = order.orderData;

            // Update stock Levels
            for (const item of orderData) {
                const product = await Products.findOne({productCode: item.productCode});
                await increaseQuantity(product.quantity, item.quantity, item.productCode);
            }
            // Update Purchases Table
            await updateOrderStatusPurchases(orderID);
            // Update TxnAudit Table
            await updateStatusTXN_AUDIT(orderID);
        }

        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Pending orders received'});
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while canceling orders' });
    }
  });
```

Comment: Hi Mirak, unfortunately this is not the case because I am able to print the order ID and it gives me a single string value and trying `orderIDs.split(',')`  gives me the error `error: orderIDs.split is not a function or its return value is not iterable {"timestamp":"2023-11-01T17:58:44.284Z"}`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).